# Selecting features and save them as a new polygon while removing the selected features from input polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, select

I have a shapefile with ~ 50.000 features.
I would like to manually extract ~ 10.000 features to test my model after its training.

Is it possible to make a manual selection like you see here, save the selection as a new shapefile while in the same time removing the selected part from the initial shapefile ?

Or maybe even better, create another shapefile from the non-selected layer ? I guess this is not possible in one step, but maybe save first the new shapefile and the "substract" the new shapefile from the initial one ?

I work with QGIS 3.22.10 on Mac OS.

[image]

Comment: How did you select the highlited features ? Depending on your answer, you could use "Extract by selected features", "Extract by expression" or create an extra polygon to use Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Clip or Difference.

Comment: I selected them manually, thanks for the tip anyway !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have made your selection, you can

1. `Edit > Cut features` and then
2. `Edit > Paste features as... > Choose between New Vector Layer or Temporary Scratch Layer`

[image]

Make sure the layer you are cutting from is in Edit mode. You can enable it using `Layer` > `Toggle Editing`.